# Tastypie Urls and Filters

Tags: tastypie

I would like to use tastypie with some slightly different urls.  I would like them to be like this:

/api/v1/city/London/make_default
/api/v1/city/Paris/make_default
/api/v1/city/Singapore/remove_city

Where the city itself can be any city in the city table in my db and the resource name is the method I want to perform.  Each method has it's own resource.  In tastypie the urls seem to give me some trouble with this.  The prepend_urls that I have keep giving me a 301 redirect.

```
class CityResource(Resource):
    class Meta

     def make_default(self, request, city_name):
        return super(ViewTemplateResource, self).get_object_list(request)\
                        .filter(name=city_name, client=request.user).update(default=True)

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^city/(?P<city_id>[\w\d_.-]+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name,
                                   self.wrap_view('make_default')),
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I did it a bit differently:

first the wrap view was avoiding the normal pathway of tastypie instead of adding to it:

```
def dispatch_default(self, request, city_name, **kwargs):
    self.queryset = City.objects.filter(name=city_name, client=user)
    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)  # could use super here too instead of copying the normal code


def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^city/(.+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)$" % self._meta.resource_name,
                                   self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail')),
                ]
```